# jQueryMobile tabs not working in dialog

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-dialog, jquery-tabs

I'm using jQueryMobile 1.4.
This is the version where they introduce [tabs](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/tabs/).

I can get the dialogs working by itself. I can also get the tabs working by itself, but when it's paired with dialog, it doesn't seem to work.

I have a toy example that illustrates the problem at [github](https://github.com/kanesee/jqm-dialog-tabs).

If you go directly to the dialog.html page, then the dialog and tabs work fine.

But if you start from the index.html page, then click on the link to pop open the dialog, the process fails. What happens is that the dialog pops up momentarily, but then disappears again. The url also changes to dialog.html, but the content is that of index.html.

My index.html opens the dialog page with this code:

```
$('#info').on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer('change','dialog.html');
});
```

My dialog.html is simply this:

```
<div data-role="page" data-dialog="true">

<div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
  <h1>Dialog</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content" data-theme="c">
  <div data-role="tabs">
    <div data-role="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#tab1" data-ajax="false">tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-ajax="false">tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3" data-ajax="false">tab3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="tab1">
      Content1
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
      Content2
    </div>
    <div id="tab3">
      Content3
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- content -->
```

Comment: it's a bug https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/7169

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'll try the _createWidget workaround listed in there, and pray the next release of jQM 1.4 addresses this

Comment: Oh hey Omar! Is this the same Omar that answered my last page event question? Thank you again!

Comment: Yup the same ;) the fix is scheduled to be released in JQM 1.5. You're welcome!